# What does 'bound to the same object' mean for C++ iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, language-lawyer, reverse-iterator

I found this article 'How to write an STL compatible container' https://medium.com/p/fc5b994462c6

The author, Vanand Gasparyan, had issues around one of the requirements of an iterator that he refers to in his article
[ If a and b are both dereferenceable, then a == b if and only if *a and *b are bound to the same object. ].
He mentions this in terms of converting a forward-iterator to a reverse-iterator.

I read the C++2x standard and found the requirement mentioned by Vanand in section 25.3.5.5, but have not yet found a 'definition' of the phrase 'bound to the same object'.

===

I want to reconstruct the key from traversal of the TRIE, and to set the value returned from find() etc to be `using value_type = std::pair<const key_type, & mapped_type>;`
rather than
`using value_type = std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>;`

This seems reasonable, to me, assuming that the object referred to in the requirements is the mapped_type object.

Comment: Another way of putting it would be "if `*a` and `*b` refer to the same object".

Comment: The value type is the one that is actually used to store the objects in the underlying data structure. For trees with a key like map and trie this is usually `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`. You don't want to store a reference to the mapped type but the value. `*a` would give you a reference to that referenced value type object.
So if `*a` and `*b` both reference the same entry they usually reference the same pair.

Comment: Simon, would it be reasonable to change the return type of find() et al. to ```find_type = std::pair<const key_type, & T>``` and change the stored type to ```value_type = mapped_type```?

Comment: Probably not, the find function should return a (const) iterator so that it can be used in place of `std(::ranges)::find`. You provide it as a convenient alternative to allow your structure to be searched by key only, rather than by its value type, which is the pair.

Answer (score 1):

For forward iterators<sup>1</sup>, the standard requires `*` to [return a reference](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.cpp17#forward.iterators-1.3). Thus *"bound to the same object"* simply means `&a == &b` (or rather `std::addressof(a) == std::addressof(b)`).

---

<sup>1</sup> I mean *Cpp17ForwardIterator* named requirement, not C++20 `std::forward_iterator`.